# Twitter feed not showing up in Webpage

Tags: html, css, twitter

I am a beginner with developing websites. I ran into this problem. I would be really glad if I am helped with the same.

I want to incorporate twitter feed in my webpage. I got the script from twitter.com for displaying feeds by creating a widget. When I display just the twitter feed inmy HTML page it works. But when I try to include inside my div tag, it doesn't show up.

The Following is the code snippet

```
  <div class="span3 right tc-sidebar">
  <div id="right" class="widget-area" role="complementary">           
  <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/xxx" data-widget-id="xxx">Tweets by @_Harish_vK</a>
  <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>     
    </div>
    </div>
```

U tried every possible thing I can. Please help me out . Since I have can only use the CSS which are already available for my organization(policy), is there a way to do it without modifying those CSS?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by making a separate page for twitter feed and including it in an iframe under the divs.

Thank you guys!